# Python elasticsearch-dsl doctype update timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout

I have a model defined in Python using elasticsearch-dsl like this:

```
class Fruit(DocType):
    class Meta:
        doc_type = 'fruit'

    class Index:
        doc_type = 'fruit'

    index_name = 'fruits'
    
    ...
```

and I use `update` method to update one of the fields on this model like this:

```
def update_color(self, color):
    self.update(color=color)
```

question is how I can define timeout on updating? My clients' infra sucks and ES throws timeouts quite often, and I want to increase it for this update operation like I do this on the `Search` object:

```
search_obj.update_from_dict({'timeout': '60s'})
```

I can't find any way of setting the timeout on the update operation of DocType...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this...

`update` from DocType has no option to set timeout however if we go deeper in `update` of `elasticsearch-dsl` there is an `update` from `elasticsearch` package and here we can set some timeout. I worked around this and used `update` from `elasticsearch` package instead of `elasticsearch-dsl` one.